# ¿Cómo puedo usar un trackbar en mi formulario de aplicación de visor de imágenes para ampliar la imagen usando un picturebox?

Tags: c#

Mi código es el siguiente pero no funciona.
No hace nada, la imagen queda igual, no aumenta de tamaño con el trackbar.

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    private Bitmap TheImageOpened;
    private Rectangle TheImageRectThatCanBeManipulated;

    private int TrackBarCenter = 8;

    public Form4()
    {
        // This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        TrackBar1.Minimum = 1;
        TrackBar1.Maximum = 16;
        TrackBar1.Value = TrackBarCenter;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files|*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp";
        OpenFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
        OpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;        
        if (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            TheImageOpened = new Bitmap(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
            TheImageRectThatCanBeManipulated = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, TheImageOpened.Size);
            PictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        OpenFileDialog.Reset();
        OpenFileDialog.Dispose();

    }

    private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TheImageOpened != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(TheImageOpened, TheImageRectThatCanBeManipulated);
        }
    }

    private void TrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TheImageOpened != null)
        {
            TheImageRectThatCanBeManipulated.Width = TheImageOpened.Width * (TrackBar1.Value / TrackBarCenter);
            TheImageRectThatCanBeManipulated.Height = TheImageOpened.Height * (TrackBar1.Value / TrackBarCenter);
            PictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Ryuzaki, bienvenid@. Debes explicar más. "pero no me funciona". Te da error? no te sale? el resultado no es el esperado? Un saludo

Comment: mas alla de que la pregunta no es clara, y no especificas donde esta el error, no estas usando un componente que manipule una imagen, si no que la estas dibujando a mano... entonces... deberias agrandar y achicar el contenedor de la imagen?

Comment: La idea es agrandar y achicar la imagen por medio del Trackbar, y el error seria que al momento de intentar aumentar o achicar no hace nada, la imagen continua igual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, en tu código tienes varios problemas. El primero y probablemente mas importante está aqui:

```
...Width = TheImageOpened.Width * (TrackBar1.Value / TrackBarCenter);
```

Tanto `TrackBar1.Value` como `TrackBarCenter` son valores de tipo int, asi que por ejemplo `10/6` en realidad da como resultado... `1`.

Otro problema es tu forma de calcular el *ratio* por el que quieres aumentar/disminuir el zoom. Yo lo que haría sería usar el value del trackbar y dividirlo entre 10 por ejemplo.

Te pongo un ejemplo de las modificaciones que yo haría:

```
public Form4()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TrackBar1.Minimum = 1;
    TrackBar1.Maximum = 20;
    TrackBar1.Value = 10;
}

...

private void TrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TheImageOpened != null)
    {
        double ratio = (double)(TrackBar1.Value/10m);
        TheImageRectThatCanBeManipulated.Width = (int)((double)TheImageOpened.Width * ratio);
        TheImageRectThatCanBeManipulated.Height = (int)((double)TheImageOpened.Width * ratio);
        PictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Se puede ajustar mas a tu gusto, pero creo que este código te ayudará a ver como hacer que funcione.

Comment: Tenías razón, muchas gracias Pikoh.