# Aumentar y disminuir tamaño de una imagen con un Trackbar

Tags: c#

Mi problema es el siguiente y espero entiendan.
La idea es ocupar un `Trackbar` para aumentar y disminuir el tamaño de una imagen que se muestra en un `PictureBox`, la imagen es llamada de mi base de datos y se muestra en el `PictureBox`.

La imagen la manejo con un array de Bits, utilizando Sql Server 2008,los formatos de imagen que guardo son "jpg","png".

La pregunta es:
¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo lograr aumentar y disminuir el tamaño de la imagen?
Espero a verme explicado.

Comment: Primero aclara varios puntos, como manejas la imagen en BD, sí como un array de bits, o más bien manejas la ruta de la imagen, en que base de datos guardas la imagen, que formato de imagen usas (jpg, png, tiff) y en verdad no logro entender cual es tu problema, sí el llamar la imagen desde la base de datos o más bien el cambiar el tamaño con el TrackBar. Además agrega el código que usas, para ver sí tienes algún problema en el.

Comment: Ocupo arrays de bits para guardarla las imagenes, utilizo sql server 2008, formatos "jpg", "png", el problema es ¿Como hago para cambiar el tamaño de la imagen?, y no tengo codigo alguno.

Comment: no es lo mismo que preguntabas aca: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50999/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-usar-un-trackbar-en-mi-formulario-de-aplicaci%C3%B3n-de-visor-de-im%C3%A1genes?

Comment: y por favor si tuviste una respuesta favorable, acepta la respuesta.

Comment: Si, pero con ese codigo tengo que cargar la imagen, o sea, poner la ruta.

Comment: Voy a votar para cerrar esta pregunta. En tu anterior pregunta(que por cierto no aceptaste) ya preguntabas por el zoom de una imagen. En esta entiendo que el problema no es el del titulo, si no cargar un array de bits en un Bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para redimensionar una imagen, aquí te dejo una función:

```
public Image CambiarTamanoImagen(Image pImagen, int pAncho, int pAlto)
{
    //creamos un bitmap con el nuevo tamaño
    Bitmap vBitmap = new Bitmap(pAncho, pAlto);
    //creamos un graphics tomando como base el nuevo Bitmap
    using (Graphics vGraphics = Graphics.FromImage((Image)vBitmap))
    {
        //especificamos el tipo de transformación, se escoge esta para no perder calidad.
        vGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        //Se dibuja la nueva imagen
        vGraphics.DrawImage(pImagen, 0, 0, pAncho, pAlto);
    }
    //retornamos la nueva imagen
    return (Image)vBitmap;
}
```

Dicha función la puedes llamar en el evento `Scroll` del `Trackbar`

```
private void trackBar_Scroll(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    double valor = (double)trackBar.Value;
    CambiarTamanoImagen(tuImagen, valor+AnchoOriginal, valor+LargoOriginal)
}
```

**Nota:**

1. Debes guardar los valores de la imagen original, por sí el scroll vuelve al inicio.
2. La forma de aumentar la puedes hacer como yo, simplemente sumando, o puedes multiplicar o inventarte tu propia formula para calcular los nuevos tamaños

Comment: Randall Sandoval, lo que quiero es evitar poner la ruta de la imagen, la imagen se carga al momento de buscar un registro, lo que no logro hacer es que amunte o dismunuya el tamaño con el Trackbar